# Django form input and action linking

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How do you pass form inputs to a form action in Django?  I tried this but it's not working

```
<form action="/search?search_term=q" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: whereis your `{% csrf_token %}`?

Comment: You don't need a CSRF token on a GET request. A GET request should be idempotent and read-only. They are considered "safe". As a practical point, if you put a CSRF in a GET request then you won't be able to bookmark a search because navigating to `/search?q=term` via a link would fail the CSRF check. You don't want that.

Comment: @SancaKembang "The ideal solution is to only include the CSRF token in POST requests and modify server-side actions that have state changing affect to only respond to POST requests. This is in fact what the RFC 2616 requires for GET requests. If sensitive server-side actions are guaranteed to only ever respond to POST requests, then there is no need to include the token in GET requests." via https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a method `GET` in `form`, then You don't need to append parameters explicitly in the URL. When the user submits the form your parameter will automatically append in the URL as `key-value` pairs.

**Example**

```
  <form action="search" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="search_item1">
        <input type="text" name="search_item2">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </form>
```

When a user hit submit button then your parameter(`serach_item1` and `serach_item2`) will append implicitly in action URL. where keys are input fields name attribute 
Now your URL looks like

```
www.example.com/search?search_item1=<serach1>&search_item2=<serach2>
```

Comment: No CSRF needed for a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking how to link an HTML form to a view function for processing. Note that in Django, we don't call them actions.

Here's the basic form and placeholder for the search results that you'd put in a Django template:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

{% if search_results %}
   Display search results here.
{% endif %}
```

If you type `apple` into the text field and then click the search button on this form it will make a GET request to `/search?q=apple`.

You will need to route the request via a URLconf to a view function to do the processing.

The entry in the URLconf may look like the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from app import views


urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^search/$', views.search),
    # ...
]
```

`views.search` is the view function that does the processing. Here's a possible implementation:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')

    if q is None:
        return render(request, 'app/search.html')

    search_results = perform_search(q)
    context = { 'search_results': search_results }

    return render(request, 'app/search.html', context)
```

Where `perform_search` is a function you'd need to write to do the actual searching.

Answer (score 0):

To pass GET arguments to the page you don't need to specify it in `action` attribute.

Just do follow:

```
<form method="GET" action="search/">
    <input type="text" name="search_term" value="{{ request.GET.search_term }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

this will redirect you to the page `http://yourdomain.com/search?search_term=search_text`.

Please note I replaced input `name` attribute to rename GET argument to `search_term`. Also I added `value` attribute to display current search text to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

shuboy2014 and neverwalkaloner are correct. But a fact they didn't tell you is that you'll pass empty values if you declare no values in that fields. For example:

```
<form method="GET" action="search/">
  <input type="text" name="search_term">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

That would create an URL like `http://yourdomain.com/search?search_term=`, which could lead to unexpected errors in the View later. You either should do `request.GET.get("search_term")` to avoid exceptions or modify the `submit` function of your form to dinamically remove the names of those empty fields.